# How do I use Ammo.btCompoundShape (JavaScript port of Bullet Physics)?

Tags: javascript, bullet, ammo.js

I'm using Ammo.js, a direct JavaScript port of C++ Bullet Physics. The unfortunate result being that the documentation is C++, not great reading if your languages are Python and JavaScript.

I have the [documentation for `Ammo.btCompoundShape` here](https://pybullet.org/Bullet/BulletFull/classbtCompoundShape.html) but can't make sense of it.

I have a working code here where the `Bone` instance just falls through the floor, as you'll see. Don't worry about the naming of "Bone", at this stage in development it's just meant to test a compound shape of two blocks.

```js
class RenderEngine {
  constructor(gameEngine) {
    this.gameEngine = gameEngine
    this.gameEngine.clock = new THREE.Clock();
    this.scene = new THREE.Scene();
    this.scene.background = new THREE.Color(0xbfd1e5);
    this.camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.2, 5000);
    this.camera.position.set(0, 30, 70);
    this.camera.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0));
    const hemiLight = new THREE.HemisphereLight(0xffffff, 0xffffff, 0.1);
    hemiLight.color.setHSL(0.6, 0.6, 0.6);
    hemiLight.groundColor.setHSL(0.1, 1, 0.4);
    hemiLight.position.set(0, 50, 0);
    this.scene.add(hemiLight);
    const dirLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 1);
    dirLight.color.setHSL(0.1, 1, 0.95);
    dirLight.position.set(-1, 1.75, 1);
    dirLight.position.multiplyScalar(100);
    this.scene.add(dirLight);
    dirLight.castShadow = true;
    dirLight.shadow.mapSize.width = 2048;
    dirLight.shadow.mapSize.height = 2048;
    const d = 50;
    dirLight.shadow.camera.left = -d;
    dirLight.shadow.camera.right = d;
    dirLight.shadow.camera.top = d;
    dirLight.shadow.camera.bottom = -d;
    dirLight.shadow.camera.far = 13500;
    this.renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
      antialias: true
    });
    this.renderer.setClearColor(0xbfd1e5);
    this.renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
    this.renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    document.body.appendChild(this.renderer.domElement);
    this.renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true;
  }
  renderFrame() {
    this.renderer.render(this.scene, this.camera)
  }
}

class PhysicsEngine {
  constructor(gameEngine, physicsEngine) {
    this.gameEngine = gameEngine
    let collisionConfiguration = new Ammo.btDefaultCollisionConfiguration(),
      dispatcher = new Ammo.btCollisionDispatcher(collisionConfiguration),
      overlappingPairCache = new Ammo.btDbvtBroadphase(),
      solver = new Ammo.btSequentialImpulseConstraintSolver();
    this.tmpTrans = new Ammo.btTransform();
    this.physicsWorld = new Ammo.btDiscreteDynamicsWorld(dispatcher, overlappingPairCache, solver, collisionConfiguration);
    this.physicsWorld.setGravity(new Ammo.btVector3(0, -10, 0));
  }
  updateFrame() {
    this.physicsWorld.stepSimulation(this.gameEngine.clock.getDelta(), 10);
    this.gameEngine.objects.forEach(object => {
      const ms = object.ammo.getMotionState()
      if (ms) {
        ms.getWorldTransform(this.tmpTrans)
        const p = this.tmpTrans.getOrigin()
        const q = this.tmpTrans.getRotation()
        object.mesh.position.set(p.x(), p.y(), p.z())
        object.mesh.quaternion.set(q.x(), q.y(), q.z(), q.w())
      }
    })
  }
}

class GameEngine {
  constructor(renderEngine, physicsEngine) {
    this.objects = []
    this.renderEngine = new RenderEngine(this, renderEngine)
    this.physicsEngine = new PhysicsEngine(this, physicsEngine)
  }
  run() {
    this.physicsEngine.updateFrame()
    this.renderEngine.renderFrame()
    requestAnimationFrame(() => {
      this.run()
    });
  }
  add(object) {
    this.objects.push(object)
    return this.objects.length - 1
  }
  remove(objectIndex) {
    this.objects[objectIndex] = false
  }
}

class Box {
  constructor(gameEngine, properties) {
    this.gameEngine = gameEngine
    this._initPhysics_(properties)
    this._initRendering_(properties)
    this.id = gameEngine.add(this)
  }
  _initPhysics_(properties) {
    const pos = properties.pos
    const quat = properties.quat
    const scale = properties.scale
    const mass = properties.mass
    const group = properties.group
    const interactionGroup = properties.interactionGroup
    const physicsWorld = this.gameEngine.physicsEngine.physicsWorld
    const transform = new Ammo.btTransform()
    transform.setIdentity()
    transform.setOrigin(new Ammo.btVector3(pos.x, pos.y, pos.z))
    transform.setRotation(new Ammo.btQuaternion(quat.x, quat.y, quat.z, quat.w))
    const motionState = new Ammo.btDefaultMotionState(transform)
    const colShape = new Ammo.btBoxShape(new Ammo.btVector3(scale.x * 0.5, scale.y * 0.5, scale.z * 0.5))
    colShape.setMargin(0.05)
    const localInertia = new Ammo.btVector3(0, 0, 0)
    colShape.calculateLocalInertia(mass, localInertia)
    const rbInfo = new Ammo.btRigidBodyConstructionInfo(mass, motionState, colShape, localInertia)
    const body = new Ammo.btRigidBody(rbInfo)
    physicsWorld.addRigidBody(body, group, interactionGroup)
    this.ammo = body
  }
  _initRendering_(properties) {
    const pos = properties.pos
    const scale = properties.scale
    const color = properties.color
    this.mesh = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.BoxBufferGeometry(), new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
      color
    }))
    this.mesh.position.set(pos.x, pos.y, pos.z)
    this.mesh.scale.set(scale.x, scale.y, scale.z)
    this.mesh.castShadow = true
    this.mesh.receiveShadow = true
    this.gameEngine.renderEngine.scene.add(this.mesh)
  }
}


class Bone {
  constructor(gameEngine, properties) {
    this.gameEngine = gameEngine
    this._initPhysics_(properties)
    this._initRendering_(properties)
    this.id = gameEngine.add(this)
  }
  _initPhysics_(properties) {
    const pos = properties.pos
    const quat = properties.quat
    const scale = properties.scale
    const mass = properties.mass
    const group = properties.group
    const interactionGroup = properties.interactionGroup
    const physicsWorld = this.gameEngine.physicsEngine.physicsWorld
    const compoundShape = new Ammo.btCompoundShape()
    this._addSection_(compoundShape, {
      pos,
      quat,
      scale,
      offset: {
        x: 0,
        y: 0,
        z: 0
      },
      rotation: {
        x: 0,
        y: 0,
        z: 0,
        w: 0
      }
    })
    this._addSection_(compoundShape, {
      pos,
      quat,
      scale,
      offset: {
        x: 0,
        y: 0,
        z: 0
      },
      rotation: {
        x: 0,
        y: 0,
        z: 0,
        w: 0
      }
    })
    const transform = new Ammo.btTransform()
    transform.setIdentity()
    transform.setOrigin(new Ammo.btVector3(pos.x, pos.y, pos.z))
    transform.setRotation(new Ammo.btQuaternion(quat.x, quat.y, quat.z, quat.w))
    const motionState = new Ammo.btDefaultMotionState(transform)
    compoundShape.setMargin(0.05)
    const localInertia = new Ammo.btVector3(0, 0, 0)
    compoundShape.calculateLocalInertia(mass, localInertia)
    const rbInfo = new Ammo.btRigidBodyConstructionInfo(mass, motionState, compoundShape, localInertia)
    const body = new Ammo.btRigidBody(rbInfo)
    physicsWorld.addRigidBody(body, group, interactionGroup)
    this.ammo = body
  }
  _initRendering_(properties) {
    const pos = properties.pos
    const scale = properties.scale
    const color = properties.color
    this.mesh = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.BoxBufferGeometry(), new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
      color
    }))
    this.mesh.position.set(pos.x, pos.y, pos.z)
    this.mesh.scale.set(scale.x, scale.y, scale.z)
    this.mesh.castShadow = true
    this.mesh.receiveShadow = true
    this.gameEngine.renderEngine.scene.add(this.mesh)
  }
  _addSection_(compoundShape, properties) {
    const pos = properties.pos
    const quat = properties.quat
    const scale = properties.scale
    const offset = properties.offset
    const rotation = properties.rotation
    const transform = new Ammo.btTransform()
    transform.setIdentity()
    transform.setOrigin(new Ammo.btVector3(pos.x + offset.x, pos.y + offset.y, pos.z + offset.z))
    transform.setRotation(new Ammo.btQuaternion(quat.x + rotation.x, quat.y + rotation.y, quat.z + rotation.z, quat.w + rotation.w))
    const motionState = new Ammo.btDefaultMotionState(transform)
    const colShape = new Ammo.btBoxShape(new Ammo.btVector3(scale.x * 0.5, scale.y * 0.5, scale.z * 0.5))
    compoundShape.addChildShape(transform, colShape)
  }
}

Ammo().then((Ammo) => {
  const gameEngine = new GameEngine(THREE, Ammo)
  const plane = new Box(gameEngine, {
    pos: {
      x: 0,
      y: 0,
      z: 0
    },
    quat: {
      x: 0,
      y: 0,
      z: 0,
      w: 1
    },
    scale: {
      x: 50,
      y: 2,
      z: 50
    },
    mass: 0,
    group: 1,
    interactionGroup: 1,
    color: 0xa0afa4
  })
  const box1 = new Box(gameEngine, {
    pos: {
      x: 0,
      y: 5,
      z: 0
    },
    quat: {
      x: 0,
      y: 0,
      z: 0,
      w: 1
    },
    scale: {
      x: 2,
      y: 2,
      z: 2
    },
    mass: 1,
    group: 1,
    interactionGroup: 1,
    color: 0xa0afa4
  })
  const box2 = new Box(gameEngine, {
    pos: {
      x: 0.75,
      y: 8,
      z: 0.75
    },
    quat: {
      x: 0,
      y: 0,
      z: 0,
      w: 1
    },
    scale: {
      x: 2,
      y: 2,
      z: 2
    },
    mass: 1,
    group: 1,
    interactionGroup: 1,
    color: 0xa0afa4
  })
  const bone1 = new Bone(gameEngine, {
    pos: {
      x: -0.75,
      y: 10,
      z: -0.75
    },
    quat: {
      x: 0,
      y: 0,
      z: 0,
      w: 1
    },
    scale: {
      x: 2,
      y: 2,
      z: 2
    },
    mass: 1,
    group: 1,
    interactionGroup: 1,
    color: 0xa0afa4
  })
  console.log("gameEngine", gameEngine)
  gameEngine.run()
})
```

```css
canvas, body, html {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r124/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.babylonjs.com/ammo.js"></script>
```

The two `Box` instances land on the floor (`plane`), `bone1` falls through. I assume I did something wrong with the Ammo.btCompoundShape. There are no errors. What's the correct way?

Comment: I don't know solution but try change scale bone.y from 2 to 15 and camera.y from 30 to 0 and look at scene after it, the plane looks like water.

Comment: Check out [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@bluemagnificent/intro-to-javascript-3d-physics-using-ammo-js-and-three-js-dd48df81f591) about Ammo.js. Seems to cover this.

Answer (score 1):

The `bone` actually does *not* fall through completely, it stops in the middle of the plane.

Reason: You are transforming two times:

1. `motionState` is transformed
2. `compoundShape` is transformed again inside of `_addSection_`

This way the `compoundShape` does collide and does not fall through, but the visible `colShape` is offset (from the reference position of `compoundShape`) to be inside the `plane`.

You can see that if you try and change this line inside `_addSection_`:

```
transform.setOrigin(new Ammo.btVector3(0, 0, 2.0))
```

#### Solution:

Do not transform two times. E.g. transform only the `motionState`, but not the `compoundShape`.
E.g. remove these two lines:

```
_addSection_(compoundShape, properties) {
    const transform = new Ammo.btTransform()
    transform.setIdentity()
    // -- disable second transform: --
    // transform.setOrigin(new Ammo.btVector3( ... ))
    // transform.setRotation(new Ammo.btQuaternion( ... ))

    const colShape = new Ammo.btBoxShape(new Ammo.btVector3(scale.x * 0.5, scale.y * 0.5, scale.z * 0.5))
    compoundShape.addChildShape(transform, colShape)
}
```

#### Another remark:

`localInertia` is also applied to two times:

- `compoundShape.calculateLocalInertia(mass, localInertia)` and
- `const rbInfo = new Ammo.btRigidBodyConstructionInfo(mass, motionState, compoundShape, localInertia)`.

This obviously works, but is probably not intentional. It doesn't fail because it is `0,0,0`. If you indeed want two inertia, I also think you can not use the same `localInertia` object for both of them, but you should create a second object e.g. `localInertiaCompoundShape`, but I'm not sure.